# Cannot convert expression type 'System.Linq.IQueryable to return type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I'm trying to join 2 tables and return data that meet a specific condition. However, I get this error instead

> Cannot convert expression type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<TicketBooking.Data.DataModel.Flight>' to return type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TicketBooking.Data.DataModel.Flight>>'

Here is the red squiggle error code, my intention is to return the flight that has the specific date.

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Flight>> GetFlightByDate(DateTime date)
    {
        var query = from f in _context.Flights
            join fs in _context.FlightSchedules
                on f.ScheduleId equals fs.Id
                    where fs.DepartureTime == date
            select new 
            {
                flight = f
            };

        return query;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need [`.ToListAsync()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.queryableextensions.tolistasync?view=entity-framework-6.2.0) to execute the query.

While you have modify your query as your current query return list of anonymous type but not list of `Flight`.

```cs
public async Task<IEnumerable<Flight>> GetFlightByDate(DateTime date)
{
    var query = from f in _context.Flights
        join fs in _context.FlightSchedules
            on f.ScheduleId equals fs.Id
        where fs.DepartureTime == date
        select f;

    return await query.ToListAsync();
}
```

Comment: It's worth noting that, by returning `query`, the actual query has not been executed. It's not until you call `ToListAsync` or the like that the query is executed against the database and the results stored in an enumerable list.

Comment: You are right. Thanks for the further note/explanation. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to return a list of `Flight`. Edit this line of code:

```
//return query;
return query.ToList();
```

Comment: It's worth noting that, by returning `query`, the actual query has not been executed. It's not until you call `ToList` or the like that the query is executed against the database and the results stored in an enumerable list.